# Encryption of email address in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, encryption

I would like to know how I can encrypt an email address via vb.net code.

I found one sample which doesn't quite work with special characters and I am getting this error:

`The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.`

Here is the code I am trying:

```
  'The function used to encrypt the text
    Private Function Encrypt(ByVal strText As String, ByVal strEncrKey _
             As String) As String
        Dim byKey() As Byte = {}
        Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}

        Try
            byKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(strEncrKey, 8))

            Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
            Dim inputByteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try

    End Function
```

What do you guys think? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks, Laziale

UPDATE: Full Stack trace:

System.FormatException was caught
  Message=The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. 
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
       at WEbsite.Login.Decrypt(String strText, String sDecrKey) in D:\Website\Account\Login.aspx.vb:line 213
  InnerException:

UPDATE 2:

Encryption method added:

'The function used to decrypt the text

```
  Private Function Decrypt(ByVal strText As String, ByVal sDecrKey _
               As String) As String
        Dim byKey() As Byte = {}
        Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}
        Dim inputByteArray(strText.Length) As Byte

        Try
            byKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(sDecrKey, 8))
            Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
            inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(strText)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)

            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

            Return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray())

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: @OScar full stack trace posted. Thanks

Comment: @Steve sorry, my bad :) Friday....

Comment: I have tried your Decrypt using as input the encrypted text and the same key. It works as expected. The only change I have made to your code is the use of the Substring method instead of Left as in `GetBytes(strDecrKey.Substring(0, 8))`. I call the two methods in this way: `Dim result as String = Encrypt("test@gmail.com", "ABCD9876")` and `Dim decrypted = Decrypt(result, "ABCD9876")`. I get back "test@gmail.com".

Comment: @Steve, your change worked correctly, I had the key value as "&/?*>:>" and that's why I was getting an error. Can you please post your comment as answer so I can select as correct answer. Thanks and enjoy the weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your **Decrypt** using, as input, the encrypted text and the same key.
It works as expected. The only change I have made to your code is the use of the Substring method instead of Left as in

```
byKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strDecrKey.Substring(0, 8))
```

I call the two methods in this way:

```
Dim result as String = Encrypt("test@gmail.com", "ABCD9876") 
Dim decrypted = Decrypt(result, "ABCD9876")
```

I get back "test@gmail.com".
-Buon Weekend anche a te-

Answer (score 0):

Use an String Builder instead of string as the parameter with the special characters.

Best regards.